# Having trouble calling aspx from Ext JS 4.2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, css, extjs

I am trying to make a call to an ASPX url; however, the return keeps coming back as a failure.

I have used this url in other programming projects, but this is my first time using it with Ext JS.  I have seen various examples online and none seem to fix my issue.  Below is my javascript file and any help would be appreciated in getting a successful return on my button click.

I have used Fiddler and it is calling the url; however, even thought the returned JSON is {success: true}, it is not hitting my Debugger.Launch() statement or calling my "Success" alert.

So, it is not entering my C# code from the javascript call even thought fiddler shows the call is being made to http ://localhost/login/login.aspx.

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.window.Window'
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var field = new Ext.form.field.Text({
        renderTo: document.body
    }),
        fieldHeight = field.getHeight(),
        padding = 5,
        remainingHeight;

    field.destroy();

    remainingHeight = padding + fieldHeight * 2;

    var login = new Ext.form.Panel({
        border: false,
        fieldDefaults: {
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 100
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        bodyPadding: padding,

        items: [{
            xtype: 'box',
            region: 'west',
            width: 128,
            height: 46,
            autoEl: { tag: 'img', src: 'images/logo.png' },
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 15px 15px'
        }, {
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Company Name',
            name: 'company',
            emptyText: 'Company ID',
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 10px 30px'
        }, {
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'User ID',
            name: 'user',
            emptyText: 'User Name',
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 10px 30px'
        }, {
            allowBlank: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'pass',
            emptyText: 'Password',
            inputType: 'password',
            style: 'margin: 10px 0px 10px 30px'
        }]
    });

    new Ext.window.Window({
        autoShow: true,
        title: 'Support Tools Login',
        resizable: false,
        closable: false,
        width: 350,
        height: 250,
        layout: 'fit',
        plain: true,
        items: login,
        constrain: true,
        draggable: false,

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,

            handler: function () {
                login.getForm().submit({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/login/login.aspx',
                    waitTitle: 'Connectiong',
                    waitMsg: 'Sending data...',

                    success: function (login, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success');
                    },

                    failure: function (login, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure')
                    }
                });
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Aspx file:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using SupportToolsCommon;

namespace App.login
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static Database db;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write("{success: true}");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the server respond? The submit operation expects a json object with a property of `success` set to `true`.

Comment: The problem is, I am not getting a response back when I use this code.  Also, I have a Debugger.Launch() statement set up at the beginning of my aspx page.  It launches perfect when I go to the url directly; however, it is not launching when I use the above javascript.  This tells me that I have done something wrong in making the POST.

Comment: You're not falling to a cross-domain issue? I mean, your page is actually loaded from 'https://localhost/...'? Do you at least see the outgoing request in you developer tools?

Comment: I tried using the developer tool and Fiddler and there is no outgoing request to login.aspx or any other page, and that is my problem here.  If there was 'something' I am pretty sure I'd be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. I tested in this [jfFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/84CPU/), just by changing the url, and everything is working. The request is firing, the response is received...

```
url: '/echo/json/',
params: {json: Ext.encode({success: true}), delay: .5},
```

So you have a problem with your URL or your server. As I said in the comments, are you sure you're acceding the page with `https://localhost/...` and not simply `http://localhost/...`?